# Inverse of cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $F(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function and $P(x)$ is the (given) probability distribution function and $X$ is a random variable.
Can anybody please intuitively explain,

- Why can the inverse of the CDF give us the random variable $X$?
- Why can't we find the random variable $X$ from the PDF?
- I wonder what $F$ and $F^{-1}$ get and return?

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you want [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling#Proof_of_correctness).

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean 'find the rv X from the PDF'? If you know pdf, you 'know' rv (whatever you mean by that). The main property of CDF is that it is a non-decreasing function. Specifically, for continuous rvs, you can find $x_0$, s.t.:
$$
p=P(X \leq x_0)=F_{X}(x_0) \Leftrightarrow F^{-1}_{X}(p) = x_0
$$
also referred to as a percentile.

Comment: Thanks. Actually i am novice in this area, so i don't have a clear picture about these concepts. 
- How can we have $x_0$ in both $F_X$ and $F_X^{-1}$? Shouldn't it be $F^{-1}(p)$?

- Did you mean capital $x$ in the right hand side?

- I am a bit confused, what  $F$ or $F^{-1}$ get and return?

Comment: I fixed the answer. Have a look here for percentile: https://homerhanumat.github.io/tigerstats/qnorm.html